# Inherited Implicit Operators in C# using CRTP

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, crtp, domain-model

I have been working with MVC viewmodels for a little while now and previously have been using implicit conversion operators to convert to and from domain models. Currently I am trying to create a solution that uses a view model base class to define and "inherit" these operators. I am running into an issue with a certain "User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type" compile error, however, I was under the impression that simulating CRTP could solve this.

Here is a minimal test case:

```
// Domain Model
public class TheThing
{
    public int miTheThingId { get; set; }
    public string msTheThingName { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
// View Model
public class vmTheThing : BaseViewModel<vmTheThing, TheThing>
{
    public int miTheThingId { get; set; }
    public string msTheThingName { get; set; }

    // Define how to convert between domains
    // Edit: This is a flaw in the design
    // Problem is that a new is required before any conversions
    static vmTheThing()
    {
        ModelToViewModel = poDM =>
        {
            return new vmTheThing
            {
                miTheThingId = poDM.miTheThingId,
                msTheThingName = poDM.msTheThingName
            };
        };
        ViewModelToModel = poVM =>
        {
            return new TheThing
            {
                miTheThingId = poVM.miTheThingId,
                msTheThingName = poVM.msTheThingName
            };
        };
    }
}
```

...

```
// Simulate CRTP by constraining the ViewModel type
public abstract class BaseViewModel<ViewModel, Model>
    where ViewModel : BaseViewModel<ViewModel, Model>
{
    protected delegate Model viewModelToModel(ViewModel poVM);
    protected delegate ViewModel modelToViewModel(Model poDM);

    protected static viewModelToModel ViewModelToModel;
    protected static modelToViewModel ModelToViewModel;

    // "User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type"
    public static implicit operator ViewModel(Model poDM)
    {
        return ModelToViewModel(poDM);
    }
    public static implicit operator Model(ViewModel poVM)
    {
        return ViewModelToModel(poVM);
    }
    // This isn't possible from what I am seeing. Why can't this be a thing?
    public static implicit operator IEnumerable<ViewModel>(IEnumerable<Model> poIterable)
    {
        foreach (ViewModel toViewModel in poIterable)
        {
            yield return toViewModel;
        }
    }
    public static implicit operator IEnumerable<Model>(IEnumerable<ViewModel> poIterable)
    {
        foreach (Model toModel in poIterable)
        {
            yield return toModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing from this attempt that would allow for this to be a thing? If not, is there any other way to ease the pain of constantly defining these conversion operators in all my view models?

[Here is the above fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KURqJ3)

Edit:
The above attempt is flawed in that the static constructor must be executed at least once before any conversion can take place. Going to need to work on a different solution that doesn't get worked around by a static constructor.

Comment: what about automapper?

Comment: **Unrelated:** What's with your naming-convention? `miTheThingId`, `poIterable` etc... I get that `mi` most likely stands for `member int`and `po` for `pointer` (?). But this is not a convention I've seen before. And it seems old (and redundant). Is it company policy, or just your own convention?

Comment: It is an old company convention, first character scope with second hinting at the type. "o" being some sort of reference type that doesn't fall under other fundamental types.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I haven't used automapper and don't know that I like how it's used but is still an option. The reasoning behind this attempt was that a solution like this would allow for data and mappings to be defined in the same location as well as allow for unobtrusive conversion.